# How to save SQL server database with my wpf project files on a disc

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

this may seem like a silly question but how do i save my database along with my c# project to another location like a cd or penDrive?

It is my first time using Visual Studio.  I have created a project that connects and uses the SQL server express.
Now i need to save all my files onto a disc to be given to someone to test my project, but i do not know how to save a database to it too?

Can anyone help?
THanks, Emack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server database files cannot just be copied like other files - they're under control of your SQL Server instance.

When you want to deploy an existing database, you have two options:

- create SQL scripts to create and populate your database and ship those with your install package, and run them at install time

or:

- detach the SQL Server files from your SQL Server instance, **then** copy those files (*.mdf/*.ndf/*.ldf) and on the target system, re-attach the database to the server again
  (or you could do a backup/restore cycle - works similarly)

Comment: Hi, thank for your reply.  Would you know ere there is examples of how to create SQl scripts and how to add them to the install package?  it seems the more straight forward one. (i think).  Im not even to sure of how to setup the project for it to be an install package for someone else to install..

Answer (score 2):

Check out SQLite.  It's a local file that will deploy with your WPF application by simply including the dll for it in the project dependencies appropriately.  It has a pretty nice entity framework provider for it as well.  You also get the advantage that you won't have to have your client users instal a sql server or anything crazy like that.  I used it for my latest WPF app, and it has been fabulous.

Comment: how exactly do i go about doing this? I presume i need to download SQLite?  Would i need to change any of my sql code or queries to suit this SQLite?